# PostgreSQL: count из нескольких колонок

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет.

А подскажите, как я могу конвертировать SQL, который работает под Snowflake, но не хочет работать под PostreSQL. Для Snowflake это так:

```
SELECT
    global_user_id
    , site_lookup_prefix
    , COUNT(global_user_id, site_lookup_prefix) AS count_views
FROM cte_page_view
```

Comment: Пока не понятно что значит ```содержат```?, не содержат это null \ 0 \ ...?

Comment: так понятнее?..

Comment: Мне так стало менее понятно, ибо я понятия не имею что делает ваш count, но вот описать его поведение языком посгри - возможно и сумею.... ;)

Comment: по идее, count он везде одинаков? я думал, что вопросов быть особо не должно ) я ошибался ) суть затеи в том, что мне нужно посчитать количество строк, в которых упоминается пара global_user_id и site_lookup_prefix :))

Comment: Так еще раз,  строк? Вот ответье языком посгри или человеческим, что такое " упоминается"?(см первый коментарий),  т.е.  если это имена полей то какие данные нужно посчитать?(там число лежит? Строка? Что угодно кроме null?)

Comment: Вам нужна либо групировка либо подзапрос, но без понимания желаемого результата я вам сказать точнее не смогу

Comment: есть две колонки: global_user_id и prefix. далее идут строки: 1. global_user_id: 1, prefix: hu; 2. global_user_id: 1, prefix: hu; 3. global_user_id: 2, prefix: hu. Данный подзапрос должен сгруппировать значения по колонкам global_user_id и  prefix и создать новую колонку count_views, в которой указать сумму раз, когда уникальное сочетание prefix и global_user_id встречалось. в нашем случае получится следующее: 1. global_user_id: 1, prefix: hu, count_views: 2; 2. global_user_id: 2, prefix: hu, count_views: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верить [этому](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count.html)

То примерно так:

```
SELECT 
  global_user_id , 
  site_lookup_prefix , 
  COUNT(global_user_id) AS count_views 
FROM 
  cte_page_view
Group by 
  global_user_id,
  site_lookup_prefix
```

Возможно нехватает условия :

```
Where
  not global_user_id is null
  and not site_lookup_prefix is null
```

Comment: хм, похоже, что Вы правы. проверил мой запрос и Ваш - выдает идентичный результат. большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял:

```
SELECT
    global_user_id
    , site_lookup_prefix
    , COUNT(*) AS count_views
FROM cte_page_view
group by global_user_id, site_lookup_prefix;
```